# Firebase track user time spent on app not found

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-analytics

I created an app in react native for the front end, node.js in the backend and for the authentication I using firebase.

Now, I would like to track by User uid the time they each spend on the app.

I saw there was [user_engagement](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9234069?hl=en) but it is the total of all users. Firebase has multiple functions to analyse a user but is there one to track the user time ? If not how could I proceed ?

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics is not meant to track individual user behavior, but rather for analyzing user behavior in aggregate.

While you may be able to track some user behavior by [setting a user ID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/userid) for the analytics events, this won't show up in the dashboards and while you can find the information in the exported data (if you [export to BigQuery](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765), I'd probably skip that and instead find a baseline solution that is closer to what you need - or start by writing my own data to (for example) one of the Firebase databases.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what would you propose for tracking individual user behavior ? I am not using BigQuery ...

Comment: I'd start by writing my own data to (for example) one of the Firebase databases (so Firestore or Realtime Database).